# The Perl class method and object method

Tags: perl, class, object

When learning other languages there is often a difference between a class method and an object method.

I know that, in Perl, the class is weak. Is there also a difference between a class method and an object method?

I know the most often used class method may be the class's `new` method. In Perl I can call all the methods with the package name, but not the package's object. Why is that?

Comment: I just want to know why use package name can call all methods in the package, is there any object method, so the package can not call it directly

Answer (score 14):

The [`perlobj` man page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#A-Method-is-Simply-a-Subroutine) is helpful here:

> When you call a method, the thing on the left side of the arrow is passed as the first argument to the method. That means when we call `Critter->new()`, the `new()` method receives the string `"Critter"` as its first argument. When we call `$fred->speak()`, the `$fred` variable is passed as the first argument to `speak()`.

In other words, Perl doesn't make a sharp distinction between class methods and instance methods. They're differentiated by what gets passed as the first argument to the method, and if some methods don't actually happen to care about what gets passed as the first argument, then you can cheat and call them the "wrong" way.

Perl won't care. It usually doesn't.

Comment: so is it meaning that when the method does not care about the first parameter, the efficiency of class call and method call are the same?

Comment: I believe that's correct. Most of the time, you won't be able to get away with that: most instance methods are instance methods because they do something with the state of the object they're attached to. But sometimes you'll be lucky and it won't matter.

Comment: I believe that this is a misleading response. Perl will accept either a blessed reference or a simple string as the receiver of a method call. Nothing else will do. Also, a class method call is at least as fast as an object method call: Perl has to look up the class name for an object method, whereas the class name is handed to it for a class method call.

Comment: Also, *"Perl doesn't make a sharp distinction between class methods and instance methods"* is nonsense. As your next sentence say, *"They're differentiated by what gets passed as the first argument to the method"*, but *before* that method gets called, Perl has to determine the appropriate class. That is either a string, for example `String->method`, or a blessed reference, like `$instance->method`. If you write `$var = 'Class'; $var->method` then you are calling a class method. If you write `$var = []; bless $var, 'Class'` then you are calling an instance method.

Comment: @Borodin: thanks for the feedback, I appreciate it very much. I believe you know more about this than I do, but I think you are mistaken on this point: _"Perl will accept either a blessed reference or a simple string as the receiver of a method call. Nothing else will do."_ In a quick test, writing a class with a method which takes a `$self` argument but ignores it, I found that Perl accepted both `Foo->method('arg')` and `Foo::method(17, 'arg')` and other variants.

Comment: @qwrrty: Yes, Perl uses `Foo` as an implicit *bareword* string, so `Foo->method('arg')` is identical to `'Foo'->method('arg')`, or `Foo::method('Foo', 'arg')`. The semantics change if you use `$object->method`, hence my objection to your answer. Please do something about it as it is wrong but still gaining votes

Comment: Actually, `Foo->method('arg')` is closer to `(exists &Foo ? Foo() : 'Foo')->method('arg')` (except that the ternary is evaluated at compile time rather than run time).

Comment: Thanks guys, for the discussion I've learnt a lot from it. But which one is the right answer, I am now a little confused. Anyone knows the source code how perl implements when call with package name and instance.

Answer (score 5):

@qwrrty's answer is a good explanation for the situation, but from comments I get the impression that even though Perl makes little distinction between object and class methods,  @JackXu would **like** such a distinction.

If you want to make such a distinction, then the solution is to check `$_[0]` to see if it's an object or a string, and behave appropriately (e.g. throw an exception if an object method is called with a class name as the first parameter).

There are various method signature modules available on CPAN that make this stupidly easy to do, along the lines of:

```
package Foo;
method xxx (Object $self: Int $x) {
    ...;
}

Foo->xxx(1);  # throws an error because "Foo" is not an object
```

I'm going to pimp my own solution for this sort of thing - [Moops](https://metacpan.org/release/Moops), which not only gives you method signatures but also keywords for `class`, `role`, etc. The particular reason for pimping it here is that thanks to its support for "multi methods", you can even create a class method and an object method with the same name as each other!

```
use Moops;

class Foo
{
  multi method xxx (ClassName $class: Int $x) {
    say "CLASS METHOD - value $x";
  }
  multi method xxx (Object $self: Int $x) {
    say "OBJECT METHOD - value $x";
  }
}

Foo->xxx(1);

my $foo = Foo->new;
$foo->xxx(2);
```